# Filter n x dimensional array with index matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a n X dimensional array 'A' of the shape - (50000, 32, 32, 3)

I want to filter items belonging to the following indexes - array([    5,    10,    15, ..., 49938, 49952, 49988])

How do I create a new array 'B' containing only items belonging to these indices.

Comment: Can you add sample data with the expected output?

Comment: not clear what is the pattern and what you exactly expect?

Comment: I have 50000 items in my array, I just want to filter for items  by index basis my index array

Answer (score 1):

If `idx` is your array `array([ 5, 10, 15, ..., 49938, 49952, 49988])`, then:

```
result = A[idx]
```

will give the required filtered array.

Comment: @shaikmoeed have you tried it?  It will absolutely work with the given shapes.

Comment: @shaikmoeed It will.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of N-D(4-D in your case) array by using,

**Sample data:**

```
>>> array = np.random.randn(10, 3, 3, 2) # 4-D array
>>> filter_index_array = [2,4,8,9] # your filter index values
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> filtered_array = np.array([x[i] for i in filter_index_array]) # This is how you can get your required index values.
>>> filtered_array.shape
(4, 3, 3, 2)
```

**Validation:**

```
>>> len(filtered_array) == len(filter_index_array)
True
```